# Should language file definitions/translations be used by multiple forms with the same text?

Tags: form, language, fields, joomla-coding-standards

If you have a set of forms and some of the same fields are used on each form, do you create a language definition for each form's version of the field or just create a definition for the field?

For example:

```
COM_TEST_CONSENT_TO_PROCESS_LBL="Consent to process this notification?"
```

Is it acceptable to reuse the definition since the text will be the same across all of the forms using that field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started out following the Joomla examples and did have form or view name in all labels but found it easier to just have one definition per extension.

For circumstances where you might need an different version you can look at the 'alt' method of the TEXT api, https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/Joomla.CMS.Language.Text.html, which can be used for more than just language alternatives.